# A standard approach to rendering 403 validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

A typical pattern I see in rails controllers for JSON APIs

```
success = @my_object.save
if success
  render @my_object, serializer: SomeSerializer
else
  my_custom_error_reporting_method @my_object
end
```

But this gets extremely repetitive. Is there a known good-practice approach for drying this up?

I was thinking of having

```
def my_error_handling_render_method(target_object, options)
  if target_object.errors.empty?
    render target_object, options
  else
    my_custom_validation_error_raising_method target_object
  end
end
```

This would allow controllers to just do

```
@my_object.save
my_error_handling_render_method @my_object, serializer: SomeSerializer
```

This seems reasonable to me but I don't see this pattern around much. It makes me think there's something important I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success with using `save!` and `create!`, which will raise exceptions if something goes wrong, and [`rescue_from`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) in `ApplicationController` to catch those exceptions and render something.

Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: ->(error) do
    # render something
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save!
    render @user, serializer: UserSerializer
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm yeah, that's the approach I've mostly used in the past but it doesn't seem to be the preferred style where I'm working currently. Also, some purists will say that errors should only be thrown for genuine bad cases that will need investigation rather than as part of normal user interaction. Perhaps it's time to re-appraise that here.

Comment: I agree that exceptions as control flow in general is not great. But there are exceptions to that rule, this I think is one of them. The alternative as you said is repetitive code in most controller actions.

Comment: Well I did suggest an alternative and ask if anyone saw a problem with it.

Comment: Right, but the problem with your suggestion is that you (and future new developers) have to remember to use it every time.

Comment: I think if we pretty much never use the `render` method and instead use this it's not so tricky. But I take your point. Personally, I'm in the habit of always using `!` whilst hacking something together in case I forget to go back and handle it more smoothly. This habit will have to remain for any saves or creates on objects that are not the finally returned one so perhaps that is a problem.